# Inspect 3rd party code in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I’m trying to understand a fairly large C++ project written by a 3rd party.  As I work my way through the code in in VS2010 it would be handy if an interesting function could be opened in a new tab.

This would be similar to right clicking on a webpage link and selecting “Open Link in new Tab” in Firefox or Firefox or “Open in new tab” in IE.  Is this possible?

Comment: Not as handy as a new tab but what about the `Go to definition` context menu option of the code editor? I'm sure there's a key-combo to take you right back to from where you came, too.

Comment: Yeah. Im using "Go to definition" but was then losing track of where  i was a few steps back when loads of files open.  The key combination to take you back would be a great help. Thanks..

Comment: To go back and forth respectively: ctrl+shift+8, ctrl+shift+7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If code are in same file, you might make use of [split window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/03/05/split-your-windows-vstipenv0004.aspx) , or if you are using viemu or opening using vim, you can simply split by type :sp . Unless there are some other extensions might allow you open same document multiple times.

Different files can have more options:

1. [bookmark code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc3ed5eh.aspx) if you do not want to lose where you come from.
2. use floating windows by simply drag out the source file out of VS2010 in tabbed view, if you have multiple monitors, you can view 4 documents at the same time quite easily, you can also quick align window by press  + / in Windows if you don't know already.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The Code is in dozens of files.

Comment: comment doesn't support link so I just modified answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Visual Studio Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/), which include a **Ctrl + Click Go To Definition** extension and [Tab Well UI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/10/document-well-2010-plus.aspx).